# Erro al importar ttk, indica que no esta definido

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Tengo este programa

```
#importo las librerias

from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *


class Aplicacion():
    def __init__(self):
        self.raiz = Tk()
        self.raiz.title("Alta Velocidad")

        # Declara variables de control

        self.num_via = IntVar(value=1)
        self.ida_vue = BooleanVar()        
        self.clase   = StringVar(value='t')
        self.km = IntVar(value=1)        
        self.precio = DoubleVar(value=0.10)
        self.total = DoubleVar(value=0.0)

        # Define trazas con la variables de control de los widgets Entry()
        # para detectar cambios en los datos. Si se producen cambios
        # se llama a la función 'self.calcular' para validación y para
        # calcular importe a pagar

        self.km.trace('w', self.calcular)
        self.precio.trace('w', self.calcular)

        # Llama a función para validar y calcular

        self.calcular()

        # Carga imagen para asociar a widget Label()

        tren = PhotoImage(file='tren-128x64.gif')  

        # Declara widgets de la ventana
        # En los widgets de tipo Spinbox, Checkbutton y Radiobutton
        # se utiliza la opción 'command' para llamar a la función 
        # 'self.calcular' para validar datos y calcular importe a 
        # pagar de forma inmediata

        self.imagen = ttk.Label(self.raiz, image=tren, anchor="center")
        self.etiq1 = ttk.Label(self.raiz, text="Viajeros:")                               
        self.viaje = Spinbox(self.raiz, from_=1, to=20, wrap=True, textvariable=self.num_via, state='readonly', command=self.calcular)                                                              
        self.idavue = ttk.Checkbutton(self.raiz, text='Ida y vuelta', variable=self.ida_vue, onvalue=True, offvalue=False, command=self.calcular)
        self.etiq2 = ttk.Label(self.raiz, text="Clase:")
        self.clase1 = ttk.Radiobutton(self.raiz, text='Turista', variable=self.clase, value='t', command=self.calcular)
        self.clase2 = ttk.Radiobutton(self.raiz, text='Primera', variable=self.clase, value='p', command=self.calcular)
        self.clase3 = ttk.Radiobutton(self.raiz, text='Lujo', variable=self.clase, value='l', command=self.calcular)        
        self.etiq3 = ttk.Label(self.raiz, text="Distancia (Kilómetros):")                                                                                                   
        self.dist = ttk.Entry(self.raiz, textvariable=self.km, width=10)                
        self.etiq4 = ttk.Label(self.raiz, text="Precio:")
        self.coste = ttk.Entry(self.raiz, textvariable=self.precio, width=10)        
        self.etiq5 = ttk.Label(self.raiz, text="A Pagar (euros):")        
        self.etiq6 = ttk.Label(self.raiz, textvariable=self.total, foreground="yellow", background="black", borderwidth=5, anchor="e")                                
        self.separ1 = ttk.Separator(self.raiz, orient=HORIZONTAL)

        self.boton1 = ttk.Button(self.raiz, text="Salir", command=quit)                                 

        self.imagen1.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=10, pady=5)
        self.etiq1.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=10, pady=5)
        self.viaje.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, expand=True, padx=20, pady=5)
        self.idavue.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, expand=True, padx=20, pady=5)
        self.etiq2.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=10, pady=5)
        self.clase1.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=20, pady=5)
        self.clase2.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=20, pady=5)
        self.clase3.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=20, pady=5)
        self.etiq3.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=10, pady=5)
        self.dist.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, expand=True, padx=20, pady=5)
        self.etiq4.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=10, pady=5)
        self.coste.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, expand=True, padx=20, pady=5)
        self.etiq5.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=10, pady=5)
        self.etiq6.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=20, pady=5)        
        self.separ1.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.boton1.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.raiz.mainloop()

    def calcular(self, *args):

        # Función para validar datos y calcular importe a pagar

        error_dato = False
        total = 0
        try:
            km = int(self.km.get())
            precio = float(self.precio.get())
        except:
            error_dato = True   
        if not error_dato:
            total =  self.num_via.get() * km * precio
            if self.ida_vue.get():
                total = total * 1.5
            if self.clase.get() == 'p':
                total = total * 1.2
            elif self.clase.get() == 'l':
                total = total * 2
            self.total.set(total)                
        else:
            self.total.set("¡ERROR!")

def main():
    mi_app = Aplicacion()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

al final me da el siguiente error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\validacion tren.py", line 109, in <module>
    main()
  File "\validacion tren.py", line 105, in main
    mi_app = Aplicacion()
  File "python\validacion tren.py", line 45, in __init__
    self.imagen = ttk.Label(self.raiz, image=tren, anchor="center")
NameError: global name 'ttk' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

prueba esto para Python 2.x

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
```

Comment: gracias, ya paso, , deja segir con lso demas errores.